# Web Scraping - BeautifulSoup parsers do not seem to work

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the name of a few items from the url below. The node and class_, point to the right content but when I use find_all , I do not get back any results. From previous posts it seems that this problem might be connected to using the wrong parser. I have used xml, lxml and others but nothing seems to work.

Is anyone able to extract the content successfully?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
import urllib3


url_pb = 'https://www.pullandbear.com/it/uomo/accessori/zaini-c1030207088.html'
req_pb = requests.get(url_pb)
pars_pb = BeautifulSoup(req_pb.content, 'html.parser')
con_pb = pars_pb.find_all('div', class_ = 'name namorio')
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for your find_all method. Reference [this link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all). Also there is no div with class = "name namorio" on that page. I saved the entire HTML and CTRL+F'd it but couldn't find it. It's possible that it is a part of a hidden element, but you'd have to find/point me towards it before we can figure out the next step.

Comment: @JosephRajchwald you are right as the HTML structure displayed in the Inspect does not match the real structure of the nodes. Despite this, if you look for the item 'Zaino nero similpelle' in the code, you will find the location from which I have eventually scraped data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the website is using javascript in order to display its content. Meaning that you can't directly visit the homepage and **scrape** the content *(as the `requests` doesn't support javascript rendered websites)*. That being said all of the data displayed on the website is sent in the form of a JSON string, so in order to get all the names of the items you could use the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.pullandbear.com:443/itxrest/2/catalog/store/24009405/20309428/category/1030207088/product?languageId=-4&appId=1"
all_products = requests.get(url).json()["products"]

product_names = [item["bundleProductSummaries"][0]["name"] for item in all_products]
print(product_names)
```

hope this helps

Comment: your code is massively helpful as by finding the right URL you can basically use it as it was a sort of API, therefore I will definitely use this solution in the future. For now, I found and even easier way to collect names, prices and images. Have a look below if you are curious :)

Comment: @AnBento Hey, thanks for the update! Will indeed take a look at your answer when I’m back home. Glad you managed to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have managed to find the info I needed, hidden in another section of the same code available to inspection. I have extracted them using this code:

```
url_pb = 'https://www.pullandbear.com/it/uomo/accessori/zaini-c1030207088.html'
req_pb = requests.get(url_pb)
pars_pb = BeautifulSoup(req_pb.content, 'html.parser')
con_pb = pars_pb.find_all('li', class_ = False)

names_pb = [c.select("a > p")[0].text for c in con_pb]
prices_pb = [c.select('a > p')[1].text for c in con_pb]
picts_pb = [c.find('img').get('src') for c in con_pb]

df_pb = pd.DataFrame({'(Pull&Bear) Item_Name': names_pb,
                            'Item_Price_EUR': prices_pb,
                            'Link_to_Pict': picts_pb })
```